# Use Base-URL with Query-Loop

Tags: loop, query, html

I've set the Base-URL for my WordPress page with `<base href="https://www.example.com/" />`

```
function custom_header_metadata() {
    ?>
    <base href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>">
    <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_header_metadata' );
```

When using the navigation for a query block I will now get redirected to `https://www.example.com/?query-15-page=2` and not the second page of the query.

[image]

This is the Block, I used on the page to display the posts.

I need the base-Tag to use the One-Page-Navigation on every site (change site and scroll to the clicked location).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base?retiredLocale=de

Do you know a solution for that problem?

My current solution is to remove base and add the following javascript.

```js
document.body.classList.contains("home")
? ($navigationLinks[0].className += " active")   
: $navigationLinks.forEach(function (element) {       
  let old_link = element.getAttribute("href");
  element.setAttribute("href", "/" + old_link);
});
```

Cheers,
Marcel

Comment: have you tried this with pretty permalinks turned on? You haven't shared any of the code or block markup you're working with, it's unclear if this is a block template or a query block inside a post/pages content. Also unsure what the `<base>` tag has to do with this or why you've added it, it's highly unusual. How do you expect it to work if the URL does not change when you visit page 2? Use teh `Edit` link under the tags to add this information as well as any code

Comment: Using the `<base>` tag enables me to simply use `#links` on every page and still be redirected to the front-page

Comment: does that not have SEO and accessibility consequences?

Comment: "I will now get redirected to https://www.example.com/?query-15-page=2 and not the second page of the query." What's the URL you're expecting to be linked to?